# 3D ASCII Sine wave generator generates weird sine waves

Tags: c, math, 3d, trigonometry

I coded a 3D sine wave generator in C/C++

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define cursorForward(x) printf("\033[%dC", (x))
#define cursorBackward(x) printf("\033[%dD", (x))
#define cursorUp(x) printf("\033[%dA", (x))
#define cursorDown(x) printf("\033[%dB", (x))
#define clearScreen printf("\033[2J")
#define width 40
#define height 15
#define amplitudeHeight 10
#define period 0.1

char *values = " .,o#";
float time = 0;

int main()
{
    while(1) {
        for(int y = 0; y < heigth; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                printf("%c ", values[(int) (amplitudeHeight * (sin(period * sqrt((x - width / 2) * (x - width / 2) + (y - height/ 2) * (y - height/ 2)) + time) + 1)) % 5]);
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
        usleep(1000 * 100);
        time += 0.1;
        cursorBackward(width);
        cursorUp(heigth);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you need to compile it with **gcc source.c -std=c99** or **g++ source.c**

I expected a smooth 3D sinewave as output

My Problem is that somewhere in the formula

```
amplitudeHeight * //controls the AmplitudeHeight
(sin(period * //controls the period width
sqrt((x - width / 2) * (x - width / 2) + //controls x position 
(y - height/ 2) * (y - height/ 2)) +  //controls the y position
time) + 1) //time
% 5 // i only have 5 representative chars
```

i have an error so the output looks cool but not what i expected:

```
. . , , o # #   . , o # #   . . , , o o o o o , , . .   # # o , .   # # o , , .
. . , o o #   . , , o #   . . , o o o # # # o o o , . .   # o , , .   # o o , .
. , , o # #   . , o #     . , o o # #       # # o o , .     # o , .   # # o , ,
. , , o #     . , o #   . , o o #               # o o , .   # o , .     # o , ,
. , , o #   . , o # #   . , o #     . . . . .     # o , .   # # o , .   # o , ,
. , o o #   . , o #   . , o o #   . . , , , . .   # o o , .   # o , .   # o o ,
. , o o #   . , o #   . , o #     . , , o , , .     # o , .   # o , .   # o o ,
. , o o #   . , o #   . , o #     . , o o o , .     # o , .   # o , .   # o o ,
. , o o #   . , o #   . , o #     . , , o , , .     # o , .   # o , .   # o o ,
. , o o #   . , o #   . , o o #   . . , , , . .   # o o , .   # o , .   # o o ,
. , , o #   . , o # #   . , o #     . . . . .     # o , .   # # o , .   # o , ,
. , , o #     . , o #   . , o o #               # o o , .   # o , .     # o , ,
. , , o # #   . , o #     . , o o # #       # # o o , .     # o , .   # # o , ,
. . , o o #   . , , o #   . . , o o o # # # o o o , . .   # o , , .   # o o , .
. . , , o # #   . , o # #   . . , , o o o o o , , . .   # # o , .   # # o , , .
```

the result i want to achieve is a smooth 3D sinewave, but i don't see the error in my code.

EDIT: 
there seems to be a little more wrong than i thought if i set the period to **0.5** i get:

```
# # , o o # .     , .   o . o # # # o o , o o # # # o . o   . ,     . # o o , #
# o   . . ,     . # o o . o # # o .   # # #   . o # # o . o o # .     , . .   o
# o # #   .     o . .   o # # o   o . # # # . o   o # # o   . . o     .   # # o
# , o o # .   . # o o , # # o   , # .   #   . # ,   o # # , o o # .   . # o o ,
# . , , o     .     # o # # . o #   , . . . ,   # o . # # o #     .     o , , .
# . . . ,     , . .   o # o   . . ,           , . .   o # o   . . ,     , . . .
# . . . ,     , , , . # # o # #   .     .     .   # # o # # . , , ,     , . . .
#   . . ,     o , , . # # , # # # .   . # .   . # # # , # # . , , o     , . .
# . . . ,     , , , . # # o # #   .     .     .   # # o # # . , , ,     , . . .
# . . . ,     , . .   o # o   . . ,           , . .   o # o   . . ,     , . . .
# . , , o     .     # o # # . o #   , . . . ,   # o . # # o #     .     o , , .
# , o o # .   . # o o , # # o   , # .   #   . # ,   o # # , o o # .   . # o o ,
# o # #   .     o . .   o # # o   o . # # # . o   o # # o   . . o     .   # # o
# o   . . ,     . # o o . o # # o .   # # #   . o # # o . o o # .     , . .   o
# # , o o # .     , .   o . o # # # o o , o o # # # o . o   . ,     . # o o , #
```

which looks like its resonating in itself.

Comment: What is this new language called `C/C++`?

Comment: such a constructive comment. I meant it doesn't matter if you compile it with **g++** or **gcc**

Comment: amplitudeHeight should be 5? You're just clipping the wave where the amplitude goes from 0..10 and taking the mod 5.

Comment: Sorry, it should even be 2.5 since your taking amp * (sin() + 1)

Comment: @Jay thats it, i feel kind of dumb now. Thank you :)

Comment: @Jay if you post your comment as an answer i will accept it so it isn't marked as unanswered anymore ;)

Comment: "C or C++" matters if you have to choose between `std::sin` from `<cmath>` or `sin` from `<math.h>`. Thats just a stupid example, but in general it does matter for answers if it is C or C++, even if the code in your question in principle is valid C and valid C++ (which is actually quite rare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of amplitudeHeight should be 2.5 to account for the number of symbols. You're clipping the wave where the amplitude goes from 0..20 and taking the mod 5.